# Unable to push app in heroku

Tags: git, python-2.7, heroku

I am trying to push app in heroku. I run following command-- git push heroku master

and got folloing error

```
Initializing repository, done.
Counting objects: 3523, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3373/3373), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3523/3523), 13.96 MiB | 143 KiB/s, done.
Total 3523 (delta 348), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Python app detected
-----> No requirements.txt provided; assuming dist package.
-----> No runtime.txt provided; assuming python-2.7.6.
-----> Preparing Python runtime (python-2.7.6)
-----> Installing Setuptools (2.1)
-----> Installing Pip (1.5.4)
-----> Installing dependencies using Pip (1.5.4)
   Obtaining file:///app (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
     Running setup.py (path:/app/setup.py) egg_info for package from file:///app
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "virtualenv.py", line 2471, in <module>
           main()
         File "virtualenv.py", line 942, in main
           never_download=options.never_download)
         File "virtualenv.py", line 1043, in create_environment
           site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear))
         File "virtualenv.py", line 1205, in install_python
           copyfile(join(stdlib_dir, fn), join(lib_dir, fn))
         File "virtualenv.py", line 433, in copyfile
           copyfileordir(src, dest)
         File "virtualenv.py", line 408, in copyfileordir
           shutil.copytree(src, dest, True)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 177, in copytree
           os.makedirs(dst)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
           mkdir(name, mode)
       OSError: [Errno 17] File exists: 'flask/lib/python2.7/config'
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
         File "/app/setup.py", line 8, in <module>
           subprocess.call([os.path.join('flask', bin, 'pip'), 'install', 'flask<0.10'])
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
           return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
           errread, errwrite)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1326, in _execute_child
           raise child_exception
       OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
       Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
       Traceback (most recent call last):

     File "virtualenv.py", line 2471, in <module>

       main()

     File "virtualenv.py", line 942, in main

       never_download=options.never_download)

     File "virtualenv.py", line 1043, in create_environment

       site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear))

     File "virtualenv.py", line 1205, in install_python

       copyfile(join(stdlib_dir, fn), join(lib_dir, fn))

     File "virtualenv.py", line 433, in copyfile

       copyfileordir(src, dest)

     File "virtualenv.py", line 408, in copyfileordir

       shutil.copytree(src, dest, True)

     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 177, in copytree

       os.makedirs(dst)

     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs

       mkdir(name, mode)

   OSError: [Errno 17] File exists: 'flask/lib/python2.7/config'

   Traceback (most recent call last):

     File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

     File "/app/setup.py", line 8, in <module>

       subprocess.call([os.path.join('flask', bin, 'pip'), 'install', 'flask<0.10'])

     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call

       return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()

     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__

       errread, errwrite)

     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1326, in _execute_child

       raise child_exception

   OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

   ----------------------------------------
   Cleaning up...
   Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /app
   Storing debug log for failure in /app/.pip/pip.log
```

This stack trace  is saying no requirements.txt provided; assuming dist package, but I already have requirements.txt in application root directory.

My pip.log file looks like

```
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 126, in main
    self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 223, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle,     

bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 980, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 216, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 255, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode))
InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1
```

My setup.py looks like this

```
!/usr/bin/python
import os, subprocess, sys
subprocess.call(['python', 'virtualenv.py', 'flask'])
if sys.platform == 'win32':
bin = 'Scripts'
else:
    bin = 'bin'
subprocess.call([os.path.join('flask', bin, 'pip'), 'install', 'flask<0.10'])
subprocess.call([os.path.join('flask', bin, 'pip'), 'install', 'flask-login'])
subprocess.call([os.path.join('flask', bin, 'pip'), 'install', 'flask-openid'])
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    subprocess.call([os.path.join('flask', bin, 'pip'), 'install', '--no-deps',     
'lamson', 'chardet', 'flask-mail'])
else:
subprocess.call([os.path.join('flask', bin, 'pip'), 'install', 'flask-mail'])
subprocess.call([os.path.join('flask', bin, 'pip'), 'install', 'sqlalchemy==0.7.9'])
subprocess.call([os.path.join('flask', bin, 'pip'), 'install', 'flask-sqlalchemy'])
subprocess.call([os.path.join('flask', bin, 'pip'), 'install', 'sqlalchemy-migrate'])
subprocess.call([os.path.join('flask', bin, 'pip'), 'install', 'flask-whooshalchemy'])
subprocess.call([os.path.join('flask', bin, 'pip'), 'install', 'flask-wtf'])
subprocess.call([os.path.join('flask', bin, 'pip'), 'install', 'flask-babel'])
subprocess.call([os.path.join('flask', bin, 'pip'), 'install', 'guess-language'])
subprocess.call([os.path.join('flask', bin, 'pip'), 'install', 'flup'])
subprocess.call([os.path.join('flask', bin, 'pip'), 'install', 'coverage'])
```

Not sure if this script is not working while pushing in heroku. It works fine on my local machine.

My requirements.txt is

```
Babel==1.3
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-Babel==0.9
Flask-Login==0.2.10
Flask-Mail==0.9.0
Flask-OpenID==1.2.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==1.0
Flask-WTF==0.9.4
Flask-WhooshAlchemy==0.55a
Jinja2==2.7.2
MarkupSafe==0.19
SQLAlchemy==0.9.4
Tempita==0.5.2
WTForms==1.0.5
Werkzeug==0.9.4
Whoosh==2.6.0
argparse==1.2.1
blinker==1.3
decorator==3.4.0
flup==1.0.2
gunicorn==18.0
itsdangerous==0.23
pbr==0.8.0
psycopg2==2.5.2
python-openid==2.2.5
pytz==2014.1
six==1.6.1
speaklater==1.3
sqlalchemy-migrate==0.9
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your deploy is failing because of the subprocess call you're making in your code. The path that you're trying to run doesn't exist on Heroku.

You might want to either remove those call, or rewrite it in such a way that it works.

Comment: I have added my setup.py above.Looking at logs I can see its failing at     subprocess.call([os.path.join('flask', bin, 'pip'), 'install', 'flask<0.10']). I am not sure what should be substitute for this line?

Comment: It looks like what your command is calling is a command to install Flask. This won't work on Heroku (it would if you just ran `subprocess.call(['pip', 'install', 'flask<0.10'])`, but Heroku's filesystem is ephemeral -- it disappears). You need to install the Flask dependency inside of a requirements.txt file in root of your project directory!

Comment: I have added requirements.txt. Flask dependency is already there.

Comment: Remove the subprocess call? It was only meant to install Flask, correct?

Comment: Yes you are correct. Not sure what was the issue. But it resolved now. I started from scratch, push helloworld.py in heroku and then updated my code step by step.